# What is the preseed setting to configure a disk partition as a Power PReP boot partition?

Tags: system-installation, preseed

I am attempting to automate an Ubuntu installation on a Power8 system. But I'm not sure what the format type should be for the boot partition. I know that it needs to be PReP, but I can't seem to find what keyword (or other partman-auto setting) should be used.

My preseed config look like:

```
d-i     partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb
d-i     partman-auto/expert_recipe string        \
           multiraid ::                          \
             8 30 8 ext2                         \
             $primary{ }                         \
             $bootable{ }                        \
             .                                   \
             20000 40 20000 raid                 \
                $primary{ } method{ raid }       \
             .                                   \
             20000 50 20000 raid                 \
                method{ raid }                   \
             .                                   \
             10000 90 1000000 ext4               \
             .
```

But the installation errors out with `No PowerPC PReP boot partition is found`.

I am wondering what the format type of the initial 8M partition needs to be to work around this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After digging into partman-auto, I found that the correct settings for my situation is to set the file type as 'prep' and also set method to 'prep' as well.

In the example I gave above, with the necessary tweaks it comes this:

```
d-i     partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb
d-i     partman-auto/expert_recipe string        \
           multiraid ::                          \
             8 1 8 prep                          \
             $primary{ }                         \
             $bootable{ }                        \
             method{ prep }                      \
             .                                   \
             20000 40 20000 raid                 \
                $primary{ } method{ raid }       \
             .                                   \
             20000 50 20000 raid                 \
                method{ raid }                   \
             .                                   \
             10000 90 1000000 ext4               \
             .
```